# Need help with batch-file

Tags: batch-file, merge, copy, dos

I have a very poor experience in writing batch-files.
And I need to do the following:

directory contents 2 files - .exe and .zip

I need to write batch file, merging these two files with resulting file named after zip-file.
In hardcoded variant it looks like this:

```
copy /b init.exe+archive.zip archive.exe
```

But it would be great if I could put in my directory zip-file with arbitrary name, click on my bat-file and get the exe-file with the name same as my archive's name.

P.S. (init.exe is never changes and directory will always containt only one zip-file at a time)

Thanks a lot for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job, I think:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.zip) DO COPY /B init.exe + "%%f" "%%~nf.exe"
```